# Commutative Diagrams and Category Theory

Tags: category-theory, differential-topology

I am currently studying Differential Topology and I've noticed that *commutative diagrams* keep on popping up over and over.

An example is the following snippet from *Topology from the Differential Viewpoint* by Milnor :

[image]

All I know about commutative diagrams at the moment is that that they originate in Category Theory, however looking up introductory texts on Category Theory do not give a good definition of Commutative Diagrams, and hence I have no idea how they are used.

Where can I learn the necessary Category Theory on commutative diagrams to be able to understand such arguments used in Differential Topology?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A commutative diagram is nothing but a way to state briefly and visually that certain compositions of functions are equal. There is absolutely nothing more to them than that.

Comment: In particular, you do not need absolutely any category theory to understand "such arguments", for "such arguments" are nothing but statements that two compositions of functions are equal.